# emacs lisp to make a toggle function, global variable perhaps?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am trying to make a toggle function in emacs. I tried if statement. It wont work. Could you help me. I am actually trying to make a function to toggle between two themes thats why i am trying to do this

```
(defun switch()
(interactive)

(when (= a 1)
  (message "true")
  (setq a 2))

(when (= a 2)
  (message "false")
  (setq a 1))
)
```

Answer (score 2):

A variant of the other answers, without exposing a variable `a` to the rest of the world:

```
(lexical-let (a) 
  (defun my/toggle () 
    (setq a (not a)) 
    (message (or (and a "true") 
             "false"))))
```

Of course `lexical-let` could be replaced by `let` in a file where [lexical bindings](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LexicalBinding) are used.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
(define-minor-mode foo-mode
  "Doc."
  :global t
  (if foo-mode
      <onething>
    <another>))
```

Comment: (define-minor-mode dark-mode
  "switch between dark and darker theme"
  :global t
  (if dark-mode
      (load-theme 'manoj-dark t)
      (load-theme 'wombat t)))
this gives me a Variable binding depth exceeds max-specpdl-size
error

Comment: Indeed, this bumps into a problematic interaction between defcustom and load-theme, because load-theme ends up re-setting all Custom vars (and `dark-mode` above is a Custom var).  You should probably report this as a bug (via `M-x report-emacs-bug`).

Answer (score 1):

```
(defvar a 1 "Initial setting for the `a` global variable.")

(defun my-switch ()
"Doc-string for `my-switch` function."
(interactive)
  (cond
    ((= a 1)
      (message "true")
      (setq a 2))
    ((= a 2)
      (message "false")
      (setq a 1)) ) )
```